# WFS - Which values should I enter as `namespace` and `featuretype` - Where can these values be read?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I like to use [`WFS - GetFeature`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgmZ2.png) request, that should return a selection of features from a GeoServer data source.

The request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=namespace:featuretype
```

shows me the following in the browser Firefox:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="namespace">
<ows:ExceptionText>Unknown namespace [namespace]</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I do not know exactly where I can see on the server which values I should enter as `namespace` and `featuretype`.

I tried a lot.

For example I tried

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=namespace:featuretype
```

That showed me the following

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=%20KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f

<ows:ExceptionReport version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
<ows:ExceptionText>Feature type KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f unknown</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

**Which values should I enter as `namespace` and `featuretype` - Where can these values be read?**

[image]

Comment: you have a space (%20) in your featurename %20KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namepsace and Layer Name/Featuretype are available on GetCapbabilities request as below.
The Namespace is same as the Workspace name by default on Geoserver.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getcapabilities

Alternatively use the below url syntax when the WFS is on Geoserver.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/your_geoserver_workspacename/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=layer_name

Comment: Thank you @Ashok Vanam ESRIAu
I copied too much the example in the documentation. I forgot to add your_geoserver_workspacename in
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/*your_geoserver_workspacename*/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=layer_name